# Jquery UI autocomplete in APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, oracle-apex

In APEX pages that have a text field with autocomplete, $.fn.autocomplete is overridden by a totally different function that integrates APEX functionality.

jQuery UI is loaded, but overridden.

How can I use the jQuery UI version?

Comment: Have you seen Tyler Muth's fix for autocomplete? :  

http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/jquery-autocomplete-for-apex/

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflict between different jqueries  having different versions use  **noConflict()** method which returns a reference to jQuery, that you can save in a variable.Please check documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Hope this will help you.